# If you are a U.S. citizen, are you required to have a return ticket (round trip ticket) to travel to Ghana?

Tags: ghana

If you are a U.S. citizen, are you required to have a return ticket (round trip ticket) to travel to Ghana?

Comment: Please provide some context and explanation to flesh out your question, rather than simply repeating the one-sentence title.

Answer (score 5):

According to Timatic US citizens without onward or return tickets maybe refused entry.  However, it does not say they are required.  So it seems to be a judgement call left to the immigration officer.

Comment: All answers sourced from Timatic get an instant upvote!  Awesome.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I believe someone I know may be being scammed. I'm trying to research as this person does not believe they could be being scammed. The person they are speaking to claims to be a U.S. citizen but currently living and going to school in Ghana.  Part of their claim is that they have no return ticket arrangements but plan to return to the U.S. upon finishing school. I'm not sure if the possible scammer has asked for money yet, but there seem to be many red flags.

Comment: @Mindy If someone you never heard before contacts you from an African country and asks for hell **it is** a scam. No matter what he says. Real people go to the embassy and let the government (and/or relatives) to help they don't send emails to random addresses.

Comment: @Bakuriu your first sentence is also true if you delete "from an African country"!